# nHibernate 3 - QueryOver with DateTime

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-3

I'm trying to write a query to select using the DateTime. Year as a where parameter, but I'm receiving this error from nunit:

> NHibernate.QueryException : could not resolve property: Register.Year of: Estudantino.Domain.Events

In class **Events** I've a property named **Register** as a DateTime type.

```
public virtual DateTime Registada { get; set; }
```

This is the method that is returning the error:

```
  using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.QueryOver<Evento>()
                .Where(x => x.Register.Year == year)
                .List();
        }
```

The variable year is of type **int**, that is been passed to the method.

Does anyone have an idea of what i'm doing wrong? My database server is SQL Server 2005 Express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to use HQL here instead. Basically NHibernate does not know really what to do with `year`. I suspect you need to use the `RegisterFunction` to register a `YEAR` function.

Please read this [article](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/10/01/UsingSQLFunctionsInNHibernate.aspx) in its entirety to fully understand what it is you are trying to do.

1. Create a custom dialect in code
2. Create a function in SQL server called `MyYearFunction` that returns a year for a date
3. Then use HQL (not sure if QueryOver can do this) to get the date `where dbo.MyYearFunction(:date)  = 12" ...`

Comment: `year` is already registered for most dialects, and handled by the current LINQ provider without problems.

Comment: ah, thanks Diego, I did not know this. You learn something everyday

Answer (score 7):

QueryOver does not resolve things like `DateTime.Year`.

Use LINQ instead:

```
return session.Query<Evento>()
              .Where(x => x.Register.Year == year)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: This would hit the database and retrieve all records though, right?

Comment: @JWLim no. It's translated and executed as sql.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know `Query` was NHibernate's LINQ provider. I've mostly only been using HQL & QueryOver. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In QueryOver, you can just say:

```
dateTimeColumn.YearPart() == 1999
```

There is also other extension methods: `MonthPart()`, `DayPart()`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

.Where(x => x.Register >= new DateTime(year, 1, 1) && x.Register < 
new DateTime(year + 1, 1, 1))

Comment: I can't use the DateTime like that, it returns a QueryException.

Comment: This will work provided `x.Register` is of the type `System.DateTime`.